# Replace Value into string

Tags: c#, string

```
str = "R57 & R1 & R11"

string.Replace("R1","true")
```

I want to replace only `R1` => `true`

generated Output = `"R57 & true & true1"`

Correct Output = `"R57 & true & R11"`

Comment: Try string.Replace("R1 ","true ")

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\bR1\b", "true");`

Answer (score 4):

What about this,

```
var str = "R57 & R1 & R11";
var result = str.Replace(" R1 "," true ") //Look at spaces before and after "R1"
```

*or*

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\bR1\b", "true");  //`\b` denotes boundary
```

[.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aihSWh)

Comment: regex is worked for me because sometime space is not included . Thanks

Comment: Elegant approach is to use `RegEx`, `str.Replace()` is just a hack. I am glad you choose `RegEx` over `str.Replace()` Use of `\b` is explained by @DmitryBychenko. `\b` denotes match must be present in between boundary

Answer (score 2):

You can try *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\bR1\b", "true");
```

we want *whole words* only to be replaced into `"true"`.